# Use Firebase to fetch files from public storage (run by somebody else)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to use Firebase with an Android app to connect to NOAA's public storage bucket for GOES-16 satellite data at gs://gcp-public-data-goes-16, then obtain a StorageReference that I can subsequently use to browse the bucket's contents and grab the latest file under its ABI-L2-ACMC directory.

The problem is, all of the Firebase "getting started" examples seem to assume I want to connect to a storage bucket **I** own, as opposed to a storage bucket *somebody else* owns & makes available to the public.

Basically, I'm running into what appears to be a security, authorization, entitlement, and/or configuration problem.

The text of the error message suggests it's a problem with the bucket's configuration, but I'm assuming for the moment that NOAA knew what it was doing, and the problem is really at my end (my code, my app's Firebase console setup, or both).

#### Update

I'm feeling like this project has just become utterly and completely hopeless.

It turns out, to access the bucket and the files in it, you have to be logged in to a Google account. OK, no problem... I have one, as does everybody with an Android phone. Then, I ran into a seemingly insurmountable brick wall, that's really more like the Three Gorges Dam.

According to the instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin, it looks like you can't log in from a client unless the client itself (in the form of its SHA1 Android signing certificate) is explicitly whitelisted by the GCP bucket's owner. Which has approximately zero likelihood of happening, since I'm not its owner.

Is the situation *really* this completely hopeless? At the moment, it's looking like my only option might be to do something completely awful, like make users fetch the data files manually using the phone's browser (which can log in to Google and sidestep the client-whitelist restriction) and save them to the phone's /Download directory themselves. That would make the app so awful to use, **I'd** give it two stars due to poor usability. :-(

#### Present code:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://gcp-public-data-goes-16");
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
storageRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
          @Override
           public void onSuccess(ListResult result) {
               for (StorageReference fileRef : result.getItems()) {
                   Log.i("test", fileRef.toString());
               }
           }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                Log.e("test", "error listing bucket contents");
            }
        });
```

#### Error when it runs:

java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 400,    "message": "Your bucket has not been set up properly for Firebase Storage. Please visit 'https://console.firebase.google.com/project/gcp-public-data---goes-16/storage/files' to automatically repair this issue and then retry. If the issue lasts longer than five minutes, you may have insufficient permissions to repair the project. You can check your permissions by visiting 'https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=gcp-public-data---goes-16'."  }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Cloud Services Java library to get access to public buckets
Add this dependency to your Android app's gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.108.0'
```

Check this out [Accessing public data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data#storage-download-public-object-java).
And if you want to store objects, then check out [Downloading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples).

Comment: Does this actually solve the problem of accessing public data where the owner doesn't allow unauthenticated access, indiscriminately grants access to anyone logged in to "a" Google account, but logging into "a" Google account isn't allowed because the login client hasn't been explicitly authorized by the bucket owner? My guess is that someone at NOAA set it up thinking it was like anonymous FTP w/email addr. as password for reporting purposes, and didn't realize they were accidentally making it impossible for anything besides literal web browsers to satisfy the login requirements.

Comment: To my knowledge, a user cannot grant access to their gcs buckets to any user with "a google account". They can individually set each file or entire folder or bucket's access control to let anybody read the contents, or to a specific individual or individuals via ACL's. Have you tried out making an unauthenticated storage instance as prescribed in the guide to access the data?

Comment: It appears I was wrong about merely needing "a" Google account. Later experiments (using a web browser) revealed that I didn't just need to be logged into "a" Google account, I had to be logged into a Google account associated with a GCS billing account (which I was, when I did my earlier experiments using a browser prior to writing the original question). For now, I'm just using NOAA's Amazon S3-hosted buckets instead (it easily worked). IMHO, GCS requiring CLIENT auth on top of USER auth just renders it unusable in cases like this.